# Use of \t in gawk via Python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, gawk

I've created a Python script which creates a .bat file. One of the commands in this .bat file uses gawk (installed via Cygwin, windows 7):

```
| gawk "{print """exon"""$2"""\t"""$2"""\t"""$3}" >
```

However When this batch file is run in the command prompt (os.system), the command line interpreted \t instead of gawk. In the command prompt the command looks like:

```
 | gawk "{print """exon"""$2"""        """$2"""        """$3}"
```

If I do the first command directly on command prompt without doing it via Python it works. So does anyone know a trick to pass \t to the command prompt without the command prompt interpreting it?

**strong text**

```
File = open(sample.split('data')[0]+'\\'+sample.split('.fastq\\')[1]+'.bat', 'w')
File.write('bedtools intersect'+\
            ' -a '+sample.split('data_')[0]+'data_'+sample.split('data_')[1].split('\\')[0]+'\\_IlluminaResults\\_circosResults\\etc\\karyotype_Exome.bed'
            ' -b '+sample.split('data_')[0]+'data_'+sample.split('data_')[1].split('\\')[0]+'\\_IlluminaResults\\_processingResults\\'+sample.split('.fastq\\')[1]+'\\'+sample.split('.fastq\\')[1].split('.fastq')[0]+'.processed.merge'
            ' | gawk "{print """exon"""$2"""\t"""$2"""\t"""$3}" > '+sample.split('data_')[0]+'data_'+sample.split('data_')[1].split('\\')[0]+'\\_IlluminaResults\\_processingResults\\'+sample.split('.fastq\\')[1]+'\\'+sample.split('.fastq\\')[1].split('.fastq')[0]+'.circos.exons'+'\n')
File.close()
os.system(sample.split('data')[0]+'\\'+sample.split('.fastq\\')[1]+'.bat')
os.remove(sample.split('data')[0]+'\\'+sample.split('.fastq\\')[1]+'.bat')
```

Comment: Batch files and windows command line do not interpret `\t` as anything but a backslash and a t. The conversion is done in your code. Try to escape the backslash in your python code.

Comment: When applying | gawk "{print """exon"""$2"""\\t"""$2"""\\t"""$3}" > (I think you mean that?) The command line does not produce any errors, however the resulting file now contains t's instead of tabs.

Comment: Can you include the python code that generates the batch file line?

Comment: Done. The code creates a bedtools command which intersects 2 data ranges to determine overlap between each other. I want to write exon+column$2+\t+column$2+\t+column3 via gawk which is installed via cygwin on windows 7.

Comment: Can you try `' | gawk -v OFS=\\t "{print \\"exon\\"$2, $2, $3}" > ' + ...`?